# MPICH2: Failed to register smpd's Service Principal Name with Domain Controller

Tags: mpi, mpich

Learning MPI (MPIPICH2). When I gave the following command

```
C:\Program Files\MPICH2\examples>smpd -register_spn
```

I get the error:

```
[-1:5440]...ERROR:GetComputerObjectName() failed (1351)Configuration information
 could not be read from the domain con
Failed to register smpd's Service Principal Name with Domain Controller
```

How do I remove this error? And what exactly is the meaning of the reported error. This might help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of MPICH are you using? Anything after 1.4.1p probably doesn't run on Windows and even the versions before that are unsupported now. You might try some of the [alternatives](http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q%3a_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F) on the MPICH website.